# Methods to better my VGG-16+UNet+LSTM Performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

The task is that I am given a dataset in sequential order that belongs to a binary classification System. Per see Rain clouds over a particular city, and no rain clouds over such city. I have a test data set that I cast predictions from a machine learning algorithm that assumes that the training set is correctly classified to classify the testing set. Eventually, I create two folders with the testing data reorganized and correctly classified.  I have been reading many posts concerning how to correct the issue I am having which is that the accuracy stays constant, and the loss stays at 0.0000e+0.0. So I will start first with the ImageDataGenerator:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale = 1./255,
samplewise_center=True,
featurewise_center=True,
horizontal_flip = True,
fill_mode = "reflect",
shear_range=0.1,
zoom_range = 0.1,
width_shift_range = 0.1,
height_shift_range=0.1,
rotation_range=5,
preprocessing_function= preprocess_input
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
preprocessing_function=preprocess_input
)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
train_data_dir,
target_size = (224, 224),
#batch_size = 10,
class_mode = "binary",
shuffle=False)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size = (224, 224),
    #batch_size = 10,
    class_mode = "binary"
)
```

I read many posts on Stack Overflow about normalization, and standardization of the image data set, as well as shuffling it. I have implemented many of these features in my Machine Learning algorithm, and it has not improved. The training loss stays at 0.0000e+0.0, and accuracy at .5238, and AUC at .50, and the validation has a val_AUC of .50, and val_accuracy of .7500 which is constant as well.  My thoughts on this is that my model is either underfitting, or overfitting, or it does not assess the problem at all. Here is epoch log:

```
Epoch 1/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.75000, saving model to weather1.h5
20/20 [==============================] - 74s 4s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 2/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00002: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 3/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00003: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 4/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00004: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 5/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 6/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00006: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 7/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00007: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 8/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00008: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 9/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00009: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 10/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00010: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 11/15
20/20 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238
Epoch 00011: val_acc did not improve from 0.75000
20/20 [==============================] - 56s 3s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - auc: 0.5000 - acc: 0.5238 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_auc: 0.5000 - val_acc: 0.7500
Epoch 00011: early stopping
```

Now comes the discussion pertaining to my model, I was doing research and saw that Semantic Segmentation could improve model performance however, I have never worked with the network that the tutorial showed. Furthermore, the model had the same issue before this implementation.

#My Model

```
def Relu_Tanh_Function(input , number_of_loops):
  x = Dense(512, activation = "relu")(input)
  x = Dense(128, activation="tanh")(x)
  for i in range(0,number_of_loops-1):
    x = Dense(128, activation="relu")(x)
    x = Dense(64, activation="tanh")(x)
  return x
    
    

def conv_block(input, num_filters):
    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(input)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    x = Conv2D(num_filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation("relu")(x)

    return x

def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters):
    x = Conv2DTranspose(num_filters, (2, 2), strides=2, padding="same")(input)
    x = Concatenate()([x, skip_features])
    x = conv_block(x, num_filters)
    return x

def build_vgg16_unet(input_shape):
    """ Input """
    inputs = Input(input_shape)
    inputs = GaussianNoise(.5)(inputs)

    """ Pre-trained VGG16 Model """
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights="imagenet", input_tensor=inputs)

    """ Encoder """
    s1 = vgg16.get_layer("block1_conv2").output         ## (512 x 512)
    s2 = vgg16.get_layer("block2_conv2").output         ## (256 x 256)
    s3 = vgg16.get_layer("block3_conv3").output         ## (128 x 128)
    s4 = vgg16.get_layer("block4_conv3").output         ## (64 x 64)

    """ Bridge """
    b1 = vgg16.get_layer("block5_conv3").output         ## (32 x 32)

    """ Decoder """
    d1 = decoder_block(b1, s4, 512)                     ## (64 x 64)
    d2 = decoder_block(d1, s3, 256)                     ## (128 x 128)
    d3 = decoder_block(d2, s2, 128)                     ## (256 x 256)
    d4 = decoder_block(d3, s1, 64)                      ## (512 x 512)

    """ Output """
    cnn_outputs = Conv2D(1, 1, padding="same", activation="softmax")(d4)
    rnn_input = TimeDistributed(Flatten()) (cnn_outputs)
    rnn = LSTM(8,return_sequences=True)(rnn_input)
    #outputs = Flatten()(outputs)
    rnn = LSTM(1,return_sequences=False)(rnn)
    code_block = Relu_Tanh_Function(rnn,2)
    outputs = Dense(1, activation="softmax")(code_block)

    model = Model(inputs, outputs, name="VGG16_U-Net")
    return model
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return SCE(y_true, y_pred)
```

I burrowed code from a tutorial to see if implementing it with the VGG16 could help my case, and it has not worked at all. At times I believe the model can not be properly classified, and that it is not worth any more time. However, I have been reading that there is a reasonable effectiveness of implementing a VGG16+UNet+LSTM model for classification.

Lastly here are my TensorFlow Imports:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.compat.v1.losses import softmax_cross_entropy as SCE
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import TensorBoard, ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, EarlyStopping, CSVLogger
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import Accuracy, AUC, BinaryAccuracy, CategoricalAccuracy 
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential,Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD as tf_SGD
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Nadam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.schedules import ExponentialDecay, InverseTimeDecay
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import L1,L2
```

Here are my predictions:

```
predictions = model.predict(validation_generator)
predictions
array([[1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.],
       [1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: sounds like your y_pred is all zero

Comment: I have been reading a Book in Machine Learning by Aurlie Geron Hands On Machine Learning and I have been trying things from the book, and my independent research on the web. I have made it to read how other computer scientists are using these types of models for binary classification, or even mutli-label classifcation.

Comment: what? all i'm saying is have you checked that y_pred is not 0

Comment: I'll do so now it is running on a CPU.

Comment: @SobhanMohammadpour They are all 1s...